# "Access denied to 'X:\mydir\'. Failed to start monitoring file changes"

Tags: windows, permissions, asp.net

I've knocked up a simple web application that lists all files or a particular type in a particular folder and renders them as a series of LinkButtons in a ListView control - when the user clicks on a LinkButton, the relevant file is streamed to the user. I've done this a dozen times in ASP Classic, but this is a new ASP.NET version.

When I run this on my development machine, it runs fine - but now I've set it up on the live server I'm experiencing problems:

"Access denied to 'X:\mydir\'. Failed to start monitoring file changes"

The application is configured (currently) to use Anonymous Authentication, but eventually it will use Windows Authentication.

Having looked at the permissions situation, I can confirm that the ASPNET user and the IUSR_ServerName users have permissions to the parent of the application (and everything underneath).

The host server is Windows Server 2003 R2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem - though given all the tinkering I've done, it's hard to be certain what steps constituted the fix.

It appears that the problem was due to the **Network Service** (*the identity used in the Default Application Pool*) not having sufficient permissions to **each level** in the folder hierarchy.

I simply gave the account Read & Execute permissions to the top level folder on the drive and these permissions were inherited down the folder tree, to the application directory and beyond.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows Server 2012 I needed to add folder permissions for \Users

The permissions given were:

- Read & execute
- List folder contents
- Read